# Writing class that is subclass of Vector, java

Tags: java, vector, constructor

Just hoping I could get someone to tell me I am doing this right or not, as I have never written something like this before. So I have to write a class named ProcessQueue that is a subclass of Vector, as well as a constructor that will define an empty queue. Also the Vector will be holding items of type "Object." So here it is...

```
public class ProcessQueue<Vector>{

ProcessQueue(){}


}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not extending `Vector` anywhere. Change your code to:

```
public class ProcessQueue<T> extends Vector<T> {

}
```

By the way, I don't recommend you using `Vector` at all. Check [Why is Java Vector class considered obsolete or deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1386275/1065197). IMO if you have to do this it would be better extending `ArrayList`.

```
public class ProcessQueue<T> extends ArrayList<T> {

}
```

And in your code use a `List`:

```
List<SomeClass> lstQueue = new ProcessQueue<SomeClass>();
```

U̶n̶r̶e̶l̶a̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶o̶r̶i̶g̶i̶n̶a̶l̶ ̶q̶u̶e̶s̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ , I think similar as duffymo, you should not extend any of the Java Collection classes until it is a must-do. Note that there are plenty of classes to hold almost any kind of common collections, and you have [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) and [`PriorityQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) that can help you in your real work.

The best solution would be as pointed by duffymo, composition instead of extending a Java Collection:

```
public class ProcessQueue<T> {

    private List<T> data = new ArrayList<T>();

    //rest of code...
}
```

Or creating a new implementation of an interface, like `Queue` or `List`.

```
public class ProcessQueue<T> implements Queue<T> {

    //Queue interface methods implementation...
}
```

Comment: T should be replaced by Object as well, correct? Thank you by the way!

Comment: Or possibly even `public class ProcessQueue extends Vector<Object>`, based on the question.

Comment: @Sherifftwinkie Nope, using `<T>` means that it can hold anything. I've tested before posting the answer.

Comment: @duffymo have you read the part below the line when I say *I think similar as duffymo, you should not extend any of the Java Collection classes until it is a must-do*?

Comment: Yup, I did, but that's not what your answer says.  (I'm the downvoter, and here's my reason why.)  The code extends ArrayList.  I think a better solution, if you must go this way, is to implement List<T> and use composition of an ArrayList<T> underneath.

Comment: @duffymo answer re-edited, and yes, I agree with you in the best solution.

Comment: If I implement Queue, then I have to either declare it abstract or Override all methods, that is not what I want. How do I work around that? Because I still need to instantiate objects for the class.

Comment: @Sherifftwinkie note that you can use a `Queue<T> queue = new LinkedList<T>();`as inner attribute if you don't want to implement `Queue` interface. As said by duffymo and me, you can opt for extending one of the Java Collection framework classes but that's not a great idea, I just extended the answer to show how it would be a better design. In the end, the design decision will be up to you.

Answer (score 7):

Not, that's not right.  That's generic, not extending.

Besides, it's not a good idea.  Your `ProcessQueue` might have a collection of some sort underneath, but it need not extend.  Prefer composition to inheritance.

If you must implement *something*, start by having an API that actually looks like a `Queue`.  There's a certain behavior that's expected; make sure that yours conforms to it.  The best way is to implement an interface that enforces it.

```
public class ProcessQueue<T> implements Queue<T> {
   // Have a private collection of some sort that provides the behavior that the interface requires
}
```

Comment: Original poster -- this is the correct answer (1+). Don't extend unless you have a very good reason to do so, and so far you haven't shown us a good reason for this.

Comment: @DuncanJones: Perhaps, but unless he states "homework" or "these are the requirements which I cannot change", I'm going with the best answer.

Comment: It is homework but I can use any Java API package. So I completely agree ArrayList is the best way to go about it.

Comment: Wrong again - ArrayList is not the best way to go.  See my comment in the accepted answer for another solution.